# Component Toolbar Help

Tags: php, joomla

What I am trying to do is when accessing a component be able to access the Joomla! admin menu as well.   What I mean is in a component when it is accessed you can still access the standard Joomla! menu i.e. site, menus, content, components, extensions... However I am having trouble doing this in my component.  Once you have accessed the component via admin the standard Joomla! drop down menu panel above no longer works until I exit the component again.  My question is then what will allow me to access both the Joomla! admin menu and the component menu even when I'm inside the component.  Thank you.

Respectfully,
David

Answer (score 0):

This happens because [JToolbarHelper](http://docs.joomla.org/JToolBarHelper) is calling `hidemainmenu()`. This happens only when `hidemainmenu` post/get parameter is set to `true`.

Probably your component is calling `JRequest::setVar( 'hidemainmenu', 1 )` somewhere in view or controller or entry-point.

Either find that line and remove it or explicitly set `JRequest::setVar( 'hidemainmenu', 0 )` in the view. You can do in the the `display()` method of the View.